# Change the object state from null to a another in set state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
class SubCategories extends React.Component<
  SubCategoryStateProps
> {
  constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<CategoryUrlParams>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
     axios
      .get(
        window.location.origin + `/core/academix/categories/${this.CategoryId}`
      )
      .then((result: AxiosResponse<Category>) => {
        if (result.status == 200) {
          this.setState({
            category: result.data,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        handleApiError(
          error,
          'Something went wrong when trying to load category details'
        );
      });
  };

  render() { <Title level={3}>{this.state.category.translations[1].name}</Title>);
  }
}

export default SubCategories;
```

In the initial state I set the `category` to null and in the SubCategoryStateProps its `Categpry | null` after that I'm setting the new state of the `category` with the `axios` but after that in render it still says category is `null` why is that?

Comment: if you `console.log(result.data)` after `if(result.status === 200)` what does it show?

Comment: oh I know, one sec

Comment: please check the answer if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because `axios.get` is an asynchronous call and it takes time to execute. Meanwhile, the initial render gets called. Since `this.state.category` is still `null` (because `axios.get` isn't fully executed)it will throw an error.

Simply think these two (`axios.get` and `render`) run parallelly.

All you have to do is do a null check in the render.